# Наименьший общий предок

Tags: c++, c, алгоритм, бинарное-дерево

Решил задачу о [наименьшем общем предке](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/binary-search-tree-lowest-common-ancestor/submissions/code/18304430) рекурсивно:

```
/*
Node is defined as 

typedef struct node
{
   int data;
   node * left;
   node * right;
}node;

*/


node * lca(node * root, int v1,int v2)
{
    // Если оба узла меньше текущего корня, ищем общего предка слева
    if(v1 < root->data && v2 < root->data)
        return lca(root->left, v1, v2);
    // Если оба узла больше текущего корня, ищем общего предка справа
    if(v1 > root->data && v2 > root->data)
        return lca(root->right, v1, v2);
    // Если данные два узла находятся по обе стороны от корня, он - 
    // их наименьший общий предок
    return root;
}
```

А потом посмотрел, как эта задача решается на [емаксе](http://e-maxx.ru/algo/lca). Зачем весь этот упоротый овер-инжиниринг? Зачем использовать `RMQ`, `sqrt`-декомпозицию, представлять дерево матрицей смежности, когда оно передается всего-навсего указателем на корень? Зачем эти тонны кода, когда задача и так решается за `O(log n)` рекурсивно?

И как применяется этот алгоритм, раз ему на емаксе уделили столько внимания? Вот поиск циклов в связном списке применялся, например, при исследовании псевдослучайных последовательностей.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Данная реализация работает не за `log(n)` а за `n`. И она работает только в деревьях поиска (слева меньших, справа большие). В некоторых случаях (например сбалансированное дерево и т.д.) оно работает за `log(n)` но построение такого дерева - сама по себе сложная задача (если нужно поддерживать дерево, а не строить его).

Если кратко, LCA задача такова - есть дерево (произвольное, заданное например рёбрами) и нужно найти общего предка.

И ещё, RMQ работает за `O(1)` в среднем.

На емаксе крайне мало алгоритмов, которые не имеют практического применения.